# URL in Links converts & to &amp; making the URL invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, razor

I use the label
@ {var url = Html.Display ("URL"); }
 Click here 
But he turns me the & in & amp; and this invades the url.

How can I solve that?

@ {var url = Html.Display ("URL"); }
 Click here

Comment: No, he will be able to resolve me. It still damages the URL sending HTML code and sending Google browser code.
File: Edit.cshtml
<iframe id="VentaAura" name="VentaAura" src="@Html.Display("URL")" style="width: 1500px; height: 550px;"></iframe>

Chrome
<iframe id="VentaAura" name="VentaAura" src="https://miDominio.com/Home/FamiliasDefinibles_Ficha.aspx?id=862&amp;amp;idFam=29&amp;amp;idFamCls=22&amp;amp;pag=242&amp;amp;sraccess=1&amp;amp;tmp=983" style="width: 1500px; height: 550px;"></iframe>

Answer (score 1):

When you say, `Html.Display("URL")`, "URL" is a string and "URL" would be displayed. I assume what you want is `Html.Display(URL)` where `URL` is a variable containing your url.

---

`Html.Display(myUrlVariable)` encodes your string to protect you against XSS attack.

If you don't want `myUrlVariable` variable to be encoded, you can use `HTML.Raw(myUrlVariable)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURIComponent()`  which is the correct method to use

```
  encodeURIComponent("URL")
```